# Setting all rows to their default values MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've tried googling this for awhile but I can't find a way to set all rows in a table to default values of the columns. Even the MySQL help page was quite unhelpful in this. I kind of need this for a "soft" wipe of a database.

Basically I want to have the rows that are in the DB to be updated back to their default values, while if the column does not have a default value it will leave it alone.

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to do this. You can use the keyword `DEFAULT` as the value in an `UPDATE` statement, but there's no way to make this only apply to columns that have a default configured.

Comment: You'd have to write dynamic SQL that uses `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns` to look up the default for each column.

Comment: Hmmm, what about scripting a for loop with JS?

Comment: You still need to get the default information from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Comment: Ehhh, its just much easier to do `UPDATE table SET col = DEFAULT;` yes I'll have to do it for each column I want but coding a dynamic SQL thingy seems overkill.

Comment: You said "If the column does not have a default value it will leave it alone". If you write `SET col = DEFAULT` for every column, that won't leave them alone.

Comment: How are you going to get all the column names without dynamic SQL?

Comment: Doing it by hand. Once I write it once, I don't need to do it again. I would only need to update the script if I add more columns... plus with JS you can just have it ignore the error... which isn't a good way to handle it, but if I'm doing it by hand i wouldn't put a column without a default value anyways.

Comment: If you're not trying to automate it then it's not really a programming question.

Comment: It is automated, though. Do it once and just call the function later. Automated, at least after the first time... its just not worth coding something like that if I'm only ever going to use it a handful of times.

Comment: But creating the query isn't automated. If you have 100 tables, you'll have to write 100 queries, and go through each of them by hand looking for the columns with defaults.

Comment: If I had 100 tables do you think I would have done it by hand? Lol... it is only one table, and at max 5 when my project is finished, but at that point I wouldn't need to set anything to default after that... Like I said, there isn't a point coding something like that when I would only use it a couple times... although it'd be good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way: Export a database backup from your favourite GUI (I.e. Adminer, PhpMyAdmin, etc) It will have all of the "soft backup" information in it. Selectively isolate what you want to backup to its "default value", then add this to a script.

Comment: Are you suggesting that he use some kind of global replace in the backup file? Parsing `INSERT` statements with regular expressions is practically impossible to do reliably.

Comment: @Barmar Not at all. He has a known "default" state. Just cut and paste the required SQL code into a processor script (CRONjob, what have you) and have it run when whatever his "run" conditions are met. William has not provided more details, so this is the best I can do to answer his question.